# How can I get all my posts to other people, not to my timeline?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

How can i get, using Facebook Graph Api, all my posts to other people, not to my timeline?
I'm trying to use me/posts , but i get all my posts including to my timeline, and i couldn't separate it

Comment: Do you want to include post to page/group's feed or not?

Comment: yes, i wan't. I need all user posts except own wall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Facebook FQL API:

> SELECT post_id, created_time, description, description_tags, app_id,
>   message, type, created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id=me() AND
>   comment_info.can_comment!='' AND actor_id=me() AND permalink="" AND
>   created_time<=now() LIMIT 150

The only problem is this query doesn't return "Upload photo on friends wall"'s post, because of this unresolved bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/148353975327544. However, this FQL query should works perfectly. Kindly let me know if you're figure out something wrong with this query.

Also, please make sure your user access token have granted "**read_stream**" permission.

1. **comment_info.can_comment!=''** used to exclude "Comment on friend's Status" story feed.
2. **permalink=""** used to exclude "Lim and 林果皞 are now friends." or "People changed his profile picture.", "林果皞 created an event."...etc. You can test what would happen if remove this.

Update for comment below:

I think what you can do is extract the id from description_tags which was no start with "0", for example my screenshot, id "100003013144869":

[image]

Also, extract the created_time, for example "1368624514"

Then, do a query with:

> SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id='100003013144869' AND
>   actor_id=me() AND created_time=1368624514

I'm know it's not absolutely accurate(If 2 feed have the same created_time on seconds), however most likely you can make your job done.

Comment: Cool, it's really works. but i have another problem with it, it returns post id in stream, so if post is long it is shorting by fb, and i couldn't get real id of post, to get all data

Comment: You can navigate next page with created_time<last_feed_created_time, isn't it?

Comment: I means, that I could not get id of this posts, which i retrive with your FQL query, to get all data by this posts

Comment: " I could not get id of this post"? "post_id" field is returned, isn't?

Comment: it returns id of story like this 
"test =)" on Margaryta Sichkar's timeline."
but i need id of post to retrieve all data by it, e.g. comments

Comment: It would return something like :
"post_id": "12026000_102012023232324", 
      "created_time": 1368628159, 
      "target_id": null, 
      "description": "林果皞 posted a link to Lim's timeline.",...etc, post_id is there.

Comment: Can you test with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20post_id%2C%20created_time%2C%20description%2C%20description_tags%2C%20app_id%2C%20message%2C%20type%2C%20created_time%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%3Dme()%20AND%20comment_info.can_comment!%3D''%20AND%20actor_id%3Dme()%20AND%20permalink%3D%22%22%20AND%20created_time%3C%3Dnow()%20LIMIT%20150 ? Also, please make sure this user access token have granted "read_stream" permission.

Comment: Also, stream API is not stable for pagination, you need decrease you created_time intelligently when no feed return, because there's case when the user have a long period(compare with created_time<) without post to friends's wall, the feed wouldn't return.

Comment: can u see this link this is screenshot of problem and what i want http://collabshot.com/show/rJasUy